# need to make this query scalable/optimized for larger db in the future (remove full table reads)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, query-optimization

Been working at this for awhile now and cannot seem to get it optimized.  Although it does work, each left joined logs* table is reading every row in the database regardless if it is part of the set it is joined to (user_id's).  While it returns correct results as is, this will be a problem as the user base and db as a whole grows.

Some quick background : given an account id there can be any number of computers to it.  On each of those computers there can be any number of users linked to it.  These user_id's are then linked in the logs tables.  Each of these relationships is indexed (account_id, computer_id, user_id) for the necessary tables.

I have put the left joins in subqueries to prevent a cartesian product (a previous issue which subqueries solved).

**Query :**

```
SELECT
  users.username as username,
  computers.computer_name as computer_name,
  l1.cnt as cnt1,
  l2.cnt as cnt2,
  l3.cnt as cnt3,
  l4.cnt as cnt4,
  l5.cnt as cnt5,
  l6.cnt as cnt6

FROM computers

INNER JOIN users
    on users.computer_id = computers.computer_id

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
      user_id,
      count(*) as cnt
    from logs1
    group by user_id
  ) AS l1
  on l1.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
      user_id,
      count(*) as cnt
    from logs2
    group by user_id
  ) AS l2
  on l2.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
      user_id,
      count(*) as cnt
    from logs3
    group by user_id
  ) AS l3
  on l3.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
      user_id,
      count(*) as cnt
    from logs4
    group by user_id
  ) AS l4
  on l4.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
      user_id,
      count(*) as cnt
    from logs5
    group by user_id
  ) AS l5
  on l5.user_id = users.user_id

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
      user_id,
      count(*) as cnt
    from logs6
    group by user_id
  ) AS l6
  on l6.user_id = users.user_id 

WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = :cw_status
GROUP BY users.user_id
```

**Plan :**

```
computers   1   PRIMARY ref PRIMARY,unique_filter,status    unique_filter   4   const   5   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
users   1   PRIMARY ref PRIMARY,unique_filter   unique_filter   4   stephen_spcplus_inno.computers.computer_id  1   Using index
<derived2>  1   PRIMARY ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   stephen_spcplus_inno.users.user_id  3   
logs1   2   DERIVED index   user_id user_id 8       33  Using index
<derived3>  1   PRIMARY ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   stephen_spcplus_inno.users.user_id  10  
logs2   3   DERIVED index   user_id user_id 8       101 Using index
<derived4>  1   PRIMARY ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   stephen_spcplus_inno.users.user_id  4   
logs3   4   DERIVED index   user_id user_id 8       41  Using index
<derived5>  1   PRIMARY ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   stephen_spcplus_inno.users.user_id  2   
logs4   5   DERIVED index   user_id user_id 8       28  Using index
<derived6>  1   PRIMARY ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   stephen_spcplus_inno.users.user_id  2   
logs5   6   DERIVED index   user_id user_id 8       28  Using index
<derived7>  1   PRIMARY ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 4   stephen_spcplus_inno.users.user_id  275 
logs6   7   DERIVED index   user_id user_id 775     27516   Using index
```

**example results :**

```
username    computer_name   cnt1    cnt2    cnt3    cnt4    cnt5    cnt6
testuser    COMPUTER_1  1   2   1   (null)  (null)  3
testuser2   COMPUTER_1  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
someuser    COMPUTER_2  32  83  26  15  28  1157
```

As an example, for logs6 the plan is reading every row in the database (27516) yet there were only 1160 which 'should' have been joined.

I have tried lots of different things, but cannot get this to operate in an optimized manner.  As it is currently the reason all the rows from each table are being read is due to the use of COUNT(*) within each joins subquery... removing this and only the needed rows are joined like I want, however, I do not know how to get the counts then in the same grouped result.

Help from any gurus would be great!  Yes, I know I do not have a  lot of rows in the db, but I can see the results are correct and see that the full table scans are going to be a problem as well.

**EDIT (partial solution) :**

I have found a partial solution to this problem, but it requires an additional query to get a list of user_ids.  By adding `WHERE user_id IN (17,22,23)` where these are the user_ids which should be joined... to each log table I get the correct results and the entire table is not scanned.

If anyone knows of a way to make this work without this additional query and where additional please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your question to 2 log-tables and played around with it a bit on SQLFiddle.

=> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a99e4a/2

It seems that using a sub-query makes things worse in my example data, but I wonder how it handles things when there are much more records in the tables that don't fit the criteria.

I'd suggest you give it a try and see what comes out. I don't have a MySql db to play around with here and I'd rather not bring SqlFiddle to its knees =)

Comment: Checked it out - the first query you have is essentially what my original was.  The problem with this is that the entire table is read for each left joined log table regardless if it is 'part of' the user set or not.  For instance, if I run this on my test db it reads 27,000 rows for logs1 even though the count is only 1,000 or so (the actual users I want to query).  That is why I thought putting the initial computers/users into a subquery would solve the issue.  Your second query gets the correct counts and DOES NOT read all the rows which is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This will work out great - my test db is not huge by any means, but this took .002 on my machine to run and will ensure when there are millions of rows in each of these tables that it is only reading the necessary ones.  Never thought to put them in the select... thanks!